# Visual C++, CMap object save to blob column

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, mfc, blob

I have a Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) CMap object built where each object instance stores 160K~ entries of long data.

I need to store it on Oracle SQL.

We decided to save it as a BLOB since we do not want to make an additional table. We thought about saving it as local file and point the SQL column to that file, but we'd rather just keep it as BLOB on the server and clear the table every couple of weeks.

The table has a sequential key `ID`, and 2 columns of date/time. I need to add the BLOB column in order to store the CMap object.

Can you recommend a guide to do so (read/write Map to blob or maybe a clob)?

How do I create a BLOB field in Oracle, and how can I read and write my object to the BLOB?  Perhaps using a CLOB?

Comment: This question sounds like you're asking how to programmatically do those things, not how to do them from a [dba.se] perspective.

Comment: Duplicate of [MFC CMap into oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565200/mfc-cmap-into-oracle-sql) (same author)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMAP cannot be inserted into blob/clob since its using pointers.

first of all use clob
and store array/vector instead of cmap.